# Silex and MongoDB, which Silex Extension

Tags: mongodb, doctrine, silex

I would like to use Silex with MongoDB.
I guess the best way is to use a Silex Extension that again uses the Doctrine MongoDB libs.

There are two Silex Extensions right now that seem to provide this functionality.
https://github.com/fate/Silex-Extensions
and
https://github.com/docteurklein/SilexExtensions

Except that the first brings more other Extensions and the second uses submodules (which i would prefer) instead of vendors.sh, are there more things to take care of?

Can anybody recommend the one or the other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This are brand new MongoDB providers with multi connection support.

MongoDB:
https://github.com/saxulum/saxulum-doctrine-mongodb-provider

MongoDB ODM:
https://github.com/saxulum/saxulum-doctrine-mongodb-odm-provider

Answer (score 8):

**Update:**
The Extensions below are outdated, pls use answer above.

---

to answer it myself:
https://github.com/fate/Silex-Extensions uses the Doctrine MongoDB Abstraction Layer
whereas
https://github.com/docteurklein/SilexExtensions uses the Doctrine MongoDB ODM (Object Document Mapper)

So with the first you can only query MongoDB through Doctrine and with the second you can persist Model Objects to MongoDB as known from f.e. symfony models.

Comment: they're both 404 now :)

Comment: yep, as time goes by ;) so please use the ones from the other answer